# QOpenGLContext in PyQT with Multiprocessing

Tags: pyqt, qt3d, qopenglwidget

I have have hit a roadblock as my mix of knowledge of Python, OpenGL and googling is not enough to find a solution to the following problem.

I need to use multiprocessing (or a spawn instance of Python) to create a QOpenGLTexture. Then share it back to the main application using a shareContext/textureId.

If I work with threads I can easily do it, as I can just share the QOpenGLContext between threads. How do I share a QOpenGLContext (pointer?) to an external running application in Python?

I tried using threads with AA_ShareOpenGLContexts attribute on the application and works good. Once is a different application I don't know how to share a context

Comment: Different processes do not share the same memory space, so you cannot access a logical object from another process, unless the framework allows a way to do that. AFAIK, it's not possible to share an OpenGL context (and, thus, a QOpenGLContext) between processes if not by using some hacks, which would probably be unsafe or unreliable (or only available to specific platforms and implementations).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, it might be that context can't be shared, but there is definetly some information about sharing assets from contexts. The problem I have is that to share assets you need to do a QOpenGLContext.setShareContext which require the pointer to the context you want to share to. How I get that pointer from another running context in a different python process? I tried shared_memory from multiprocess but I might be missing what is the attribute to share.

Comment: It would help if you could summarize your Google searches and what you've tried so far beyond a "I don't know how to share context" then people can help you better. A quick search gave me [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65939206/3165451), indicating it's very difficult with pure OpenGL and the suggestion to use Vulkan to some extent.

Comment: Maybe it's also worth reconsidering your setup, sometimes I think again about how I approach a problem if it's becoming too difficult and find that I can do it in some other way :) For example: Is it really necessary to create the texture in a spawned Python process? Can you not create it directly from wherever you're in before?

Comment: Thanks Florian. As I am doing a flipbook player of multiple streams of file sequences, and  python multithread is subject to GIL as seen in the included link, once I have a cue of files to upload to the GPU there is a bottle neck that clogs the realtime update of the textures. I guess that is why OpenGL design uses the Shared Assets for Context. Is just that I can't really find a lot of information on how to do that in Python vs C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python